# Кастомный канал для сообщений discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open ('logsserver.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    channels[int(guild.id)]
    with open('logsserver.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(channels, f)

@client.command()
async def set_log_channel(ctx, ids):

    with open ('logsserver.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    channels[int(ctx.guild.id)] = ids
    with open('logsserver.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(channels, f)
```

Код получает канал для логов. Я хочу, чтобы при команде бот отправлял сообщения в тот канал, который содержится в бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так хотите?

```
@client.command()
async def set_log_channel(ctx, ids):

    with open ('logsserver.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    channels[int(ctx.guild.id)] = ids
    with open('logsserver.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(channels, f)
    channel = client.get_channel(ids)
    await channel.send(f"Канал {channel.name} в категории {channel.category} был установлен как канал для логов")
```

Также предлагаю перемене `ids` дать тип `int` что бы в бд заносился только айди а не какой-то текст который напишет юзер:

```
async def set_log_channel(ctx, ids: int):
```